# Javascript error handling catches nothing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have strange error generation function.. It is from HttpRequest like this

```
public async request(method, url, data, headers = {}){
    let init { method: method };
    if (data) {
        let payload: string = JSON.stringify(data);
        init.body = payload;
    }

    if (this.key) headers["x-auth-token"] = this.key;
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    init.headers = headers;

    let result = await fetch(url, init);
    if (result.status == 200) return result;
    throw { status: result.status, message: result.statusText };
}
```

Now, I am trying to catch with something like this:

```
try {
    let img = await HttpRequest.request("GET", "/login");
    let text = await img.text();

    let str = "data:image/jpeg;base64, " + text;
    this.setState({ avatar: str });
} catch (err) {
    console.log("log here");
}
```

What is strange, was that nothing catched, even though I deliberately made an error, no "log here" shows anywhere in console.

But if I change it like this:

```
try {
    let img = await HttpRequest.request("GET", "/login");
    let text = await img.text();

    let str = "data:image/jpeg;base64, " + text;
    this.setState({ avatar: str });
} catch (err) {
    console.error("log here"); // <--- console.error() instead of console.log
}
```

Then the console showed "log here" error. It is strange that difference between console.log and console.error inside same catch clause treated different way.

Can anyone help me here, where did I do wrong?

Thank you

EDIT: If it made difference, the code behaved correctly before, when I throw the error as `throw "ERROR " + result.status + ": " + result.statusText;` at my `request()` function. It was back to normal when I changed it back to throw string instead of object.

Comment: *"if I change it like this"* — Spot the difference…? =_=

Comment: In the catch block, Previously it is concole.log(), in changed snippet it is console.error!!

Comment: So you've set your console to only show errors, not debug logs…?

Comment: Yes.. but if I use console.log(), it didn't execute at all.

Comment: @deceze yes.. I  removed all routines only to see if it is executed or not.

Comment: Remove all the code. If you just write `console.log('foo')`, without any `try..catch` or anything else, does that output anything…?

Comment: @deceze yes.. that would output "foo" if I remove `try..catch` The problem is that `catch` clause wouldn't execute if I put `console.log` but did execute if I put `console.error`

Comment: That seems nonsensical. The `catch` block would be entered regardless of what exactly happens within it.

Comment: @deceze agreed. That's why I thought it was strange

Comment: Use both `.log` and `.error` , maybe you can find "the difference".

Comment: @hoangdv Ok... tried that, and it is getting weirder. if I put `console.error()` first, it shows only 1 "log here" message. If I put `console.log()` first, it shows 2 "log here" messages. but if I put only console.log(), it showed nothing. I don't get it. Something wrong somewhere. It seems console.error() caused something to stop execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I am not sure if this is the answer, or proper answer, but the question turned out not programming or javascript nature.

After I tried Parth Savaliya's comment, I had some ideas, and I tried to make this very simple function

```
function testError() {
    throw {aa: 'test', bb: 'bb'};
}

try {
    console.log("nothing here");
    testError();
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('foo');
}
```

and every time I feed different object, any `console` command, including `console.error()` gave me different result. The previous `console.error()` was just luck. It was varying from unintelligible mumble jumble, various strings, to no output, and finally crashed Google Chrome. There was no pattern, and seemed random. I also tried to replace `console.log()` in `catch` clause with an XHR request to server, and it worked fine. Firefox worked fine. So I conclude that it was chrome's console that was having problem. Tried to remove all extensions, cleaned cache and everything, reinstall chrome, and it was solved.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're currently viewing only error logs, like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmNkK.png)...!

Please click on the first item on the list, to show all types of log, like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzoNR.png)...!

Comment: I have enabled everything. Errors, warnings, logs, info, debug. css, XHR and requests